# How do I change the temporary directory that Capistrano uses?

Tags: capistrano

How would I change the temporary dir that Capistrano uses?

Example: Instead of `/tmp`, I want to use `/home/user/tmp`

My current VPS has `/tmp` mounted as `noexec`, which gives me permission denied errors while trying to run `cap production deploy`.

Answer (score 25):

In Capistrano 3,

```
set :tmp_dir, '/home/user/tmp'
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for these settings?

Comment: Why isn't there a single list of all the configurable points anywhere?

Comment: Actually, just found that it's documented in the README.md in the repository. Would be nice if it were on the website too.

Comment: it is documented now http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/#variables

Answer (score 7):

Are you talking about the remote tmp directory? If yes, here an example::

> set :copy_remote_dir, deploy_to

This will change the default tmp directory where the archive was copied on the remote server to the deployment directory instead.

Comment: Not sure if this would have solved the problem that I was having, as my /tmp directory was mounted noexec.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are still using Capistrano 2, `tmp_dir` does not exist. However you can use `copy_dir` instead:

```
set :copy_dir, '/home/user/tmp'
```

Link to the source code: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb#L275