# Deployment is failing on update_code phase with rvm-capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, sftp, rvm-capistrano

My working deployment script is failing with `upload via sftp failed on XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Net::SFTP::StatusException (Net::SFTP::StatusException write /tmp/20130610114941.tar.gz (4, "failure"))` error.

here is my deployment script

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"


set :rvm_type, :user

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p0'

set :user, "deployer"
set :application, "myapp"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"

set :bundle_dir, "/home/#{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0"

server "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :use_sudo, false

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :repository, "."

set :copy_exclude, %w[.git log tmp .DS_Store]
set :scm, :none

default_run_options[:pty] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do
    ;
  end
  task :stop do
    ;
  end
  task :restart, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{deploy_to}/current/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Any idea?

Thanks

**Edit:** Just checked and my disk space is full. Obviously this is my problem.  An after update hook to prevent this?

Comment: did you check available disk space on your server?  df /tmp

Comment: well thanks for quick answer. just checked my diskspace and its %99.7 full :)Obviously this is my problem. how to prevent this?

Comment: This question covers moving the copy directory for capistrano - if you have another partition with sufficient space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724534/how-to-change-the-temporary-dir-capistrano-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

- check available disk space on the server for /tmp

  df /tmp
- free up space if necessary
- alternatively configure capistrano to use a different folder to deploy to ([How do I change the temporary directory that Capistrano uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724534/how-to-change-the-temporary-dir-capistrano-used))
- you may want to look at removing old releases if you are not already doing so

  cap deploy:cleanup